# What's an easy way to get item from a dict, if not found, get from another dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to get a value from `a`. If it can't be found there, then try to get it from `b`. Throw exception if it can't be found in `b` either.

`a.get(key, b[key])` doesn't work since it won't lazy evaluate `b[key]`.

What's the proper way to it?

The following works but seems a bit lengthy.

```
value = a.get(key, b.get(key, 'not found'))
if value == 'not found':
    raise Exception()
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're using 3.3+, you can use [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)

```
from collections import ChainMap

a = {'a': 1}
b = {'b': 2}

# Add as many `dict`s as you want in order of priority...
chained = ChainMap(a, b)
print(chained['b'])
```

If you're only interested in retrieval and don't have 3.3+ available, then you can roll your own helper function:

```
def whatever(key, *args):
    for mapping in args:
        try:
            return mapping[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    raise KeyError(key)
```

Then use that as `value = whatever('somekey', a, b)`

Comment: If later you decide that you don't want the `KeyError`, you can still do `chained.get('c', 3)`.

Answer (score 6):

Use conditional expression, like this

```
a[key] if key in a else b[key]
```

If you want to avoid error, if it is not found in both of them, you can use `dict.get`, like this

```
a[key] if key in a else b.get(key, <default_value>)
```

*There is an ugly hack*, which uses a tuple of dictionaries to pick the best one

```
(b, a)[key in a].get(key)
```

if you want to get the key error, you can make it even more weirder,

```
(b, a)[key in a][key]
```

This will pick `a`, if `key` is really in `a`, because boolean expressions are equivalent to 1 (`True`) and 0 (`False`). So, `(b, a)[True]` will pick `a` and `False` would pick `a`.

Comment: Downvoter, if you are still around, please explain how I can improve this answer.